# Output file in Azure-automation script

Tags: azure, powershell, automation, output

I'm adapting a powershell script I have at work for use in Azure-automation, which outputs 3 different CSV files. I'm trying to avoid having to create a DB and send the information there since it would require a changing the script too much, and its quite complex.
Does anyone know if there's a way to just send the 3 files to some kind of folder in Azure? Or maybe another solution that wouldn't require messing too much with the script?
Sorry if it is a dumb question, I'm not very familiar with Azure yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easiest option is to continue writing the file as you are now, then after the file is written have your Powershell code upload it to Blob storage using **Set-AzureStorageBlobContent**.  See https://savilltech.com/2018/03/25/writing-to-files-with-azure-automation/ for an example.

You can read more about using Powershell to upload to blob storage, including all the steps you need to create the storage account and container, at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-powershell.

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thanks a lot!